# Error Displaying Readable Text In Django Template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send a mail to users when they signup to my django webapp. After trying the below codes so that it will get the message from a template and present it in the user email in a readable format. But It keeps displaying like this;

```
   <django.template.base.Template object at 0x033079D0>
```

Instead of readable format that's in the template. I want it to display in readable text and not like the above format.

Views:

```
     Subject='Beta Invite'
     message=loader.get_template('letter.html')
     from_email='test@gmail.com'

      def invite_me(request):
          if request.method=="POST":
              form=InviteForm(request.POST)
              if form.is_valid():
                 form.save()
                 #get input data and send email to the user.
                 msg=EmailMessage(Subject,message,from_email,Invite.objects.values_list('email_address', flat=True))
                 msg.send()
                 return HttpResponse('Thanks For Inputting Your Email, Go Check Your Email For Our Invite!')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid Email Address')
        else:
            form=InviteForm()
            return render_to_response('home.html',{'InviteForm':InviteForm},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the templates render method.  Something like:

```
msg=EmailMessage(Subject, message.render(Context()),
    from_email, Invite.objects.values_list('email_address', flat=True))
```

Note: if you have "context" for the template, you will need to pass it to Context().

Please see the documenation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/).  They have some good examples (almost exactly this problem)

Comment: Awesome, now working! the link below is broken though. :) Thanks.

Comment: @picomon - can you double check the link?  It works fine for me.  And glad I could help!